# Вывод строки "заборчиком" в python

Tags: python

Необходимо вывести строку таким образом, чтобы  каждая вторая буква была заглавной. Пробовал использование среза и метода `upper()`, но получилось вывести только заглавные буквы.

```
text = input()
print(text[0:len(text):2].upper())
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в вопрос пример результата для `"Раз, Два и Три"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например, так:

```
text = input()
count = [i for i in range(len(text))]
print(''.join(text[i].upper() if (i % 2 != 0) else text[i] for i in count))
```

Comment: или более изящная версия: 
`print(''.join(text[i].upper() if i % 2 != 0 else text[i] for i in range(len(text))))`

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

text = input('Введите текст: ')
zabor = re.sub(r'(\b|\w)(\w)', lambda x: x.group(1).lower()+x.group(2).upper(), text)
print(zabor)
```

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что командой `print(text[0:len(text):2].upper())` вы пытаетесь вывести срез строки, состоящий из каждого второго символа исходной строки, к которому применён метод `upper()`. Поэтому и выводится только каждый второй символ (заглавный из-за `upper()`).

Можно пойти несколькими путями:

**Во-первых**, самый банальный, при помощи цикла `for`:

```
text = input()

for i in range(len(text)):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        print(text[i].upper(), end="")
    else:
        print(text[i], end="")
```

**Во-вторых** чуть более хитрый при помощи генератора-списка, в котором стоит условие, что i-й символ объекта, возвращаемого генератором (то бишь i-й символ исходной строки `text`) либо остаётся неизменным, либо его регистр становится верхним.

```
text = input()

new_text = "".join([text[i].upper() if i % 2 == 0 else text[i] for i in range(len(text))])

print(text)
```

Заметьте, что тут исправлен тот недостаток, что вы в своём примере "пробегали" на каждый символ исходной строки, а лишь каждый второй, и исходная строка `text` проходится полностью.